# FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter so as to to achieve parallelism while picking files from a common shared directory. I want that 2 instances of the service pickup different files at the same time . However files are  being picked by one instancE; not by second instance

Using spring boot 2

```
@Bean("filterFiles")
public FileListFilter<File> filterFiles() {
    /**
     * with accept once file list filter if the file is processed
     * it will not be processed again . This will require service restart
     * this done for concurrency since we dont want same file to processed again by different threads
     * 
     */
    ChainFileListFilter<File> filters = new ChainFileListFilter<File>();
    filters.addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(redisMetaDataStore(), "rci-files"));
    filters.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
}

@Bean
ConcurrentMetadataStore redisMetaDataStore() {
    return new RedisMetadataStore(dmsRedisConnectionFactory(), "rci");
}

@Bean
public JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jedisClientConfigurationBuilder() {
    JedisPoolConfig jpc = new JedisPoolConfig();
    jpc.setMaxIdle(redismaxIdle);
    jpc.setMaxTotal(redisMaxTotal);
    JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jccb = JedisClientConfiguration.builder();
    jccb.connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(redisTimeout));
    jccb.readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(redisTimeout));
    jccb.usePooling().poolConfig(jpc);
    jccb.useSsl();
    return jccb;
}

@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory dmsRedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration standaloneConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(dmsRedisHost, dmsRedisPort);
    standaloneConfig.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(dmsRedisPassword));
    
    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(standaloneConfig, jedisClientConfigurationBuilder().build());
    return factory;
}
```

and xml

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="${rnr.file.directory}" auto-startup="true"
                        filter="filterFiles" channel="filesIn">
            <integration:poller 
                cron="*/10 * 0-17,18-23 * * ?"
                task-executor="largeFileTaskExecutor" 
                max-messages-per-poll="${max-messages}"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<integration:service-activator input-channel="filesIn" output-channel="toArchive"
                 ref="processSingleLargeFile" method="process"></integration:service-activator>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your `ChainFileListFilter` in a unit test?

Comment: What does this mean: ` However no files are being picked up files`? Any chances to see some logs for your application? Are you sure that `LastModifiedFileListFilter(0)` is OK for your logic? Do you clean the Redis store before restarting your application?

Comment: Removed LastModifiedFileListFilter(0) still no files are getting picked  . There is a log in the starting point of function where the file is picked

Comment: No I do not clean redis store before restarting my application

Comment: What you show as a solution does not make sense and fully not related to files polling. Probably you have some error during that polling process and you don't show it according your logs...